# How to show a yes/no dialog in AsyncTask onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialog

I need to show a yes/no dialog in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` but I keep getting

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

when the screen is rotated just before the dialog is shown. I had a similar problem showing dialogs in the onActivityResult but have since moved the dialogs to the 
`onPostResume()` as suggested by other posts but I am unable to solve this one.

Is it possible to show a yes/no dialog in the `onpostexecute()` without causing exception and without using "**commitAllowingStateLoss**"?
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: This [article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) explains what is going on and how to deal with the situation well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should maintain state of your activity in which you are calling the dialog, because every time when activities orientation changes onCreate() function calls and if you are initiating any AsyncTask in it, then it will execute it again. May be that's why you are facing the problem. Just maintain its state and then check it, hope it will help you.

Just add this code in your manifest file for that activity. Just type landscape or portrait according to your need.

```
  android:screenOrientation="portrait/landscape"
```

Thank you.